# Viewpoint .XLSX Toolkit: Writing Formulas to Excel Cell and Reading Resulting Values

Tags: labview, labviewviewpointxlsxtoolkit

I am using the Viewpoint .XLSX Toolkit for LabVIEW. I can write a formula to a cell (=MATCH(130,A:A,0) to Cell ZZ2) as shown below.

[image: LabVIEW block diagram screenshot]

However, when I try to read the integer value that is expressed in the cell, I get nothing. The formula is being written: I can open the worksheet and see it in ZZ2. It evaluates to the proper value (131) in the open worksheet. But, reads of this cell via LabVIEW + .XLSX toolkit return 0. I am wondering if there is a problem with the formula not being evaluated (without opening the worksheet). I see a utility "Calculate" in the toolkit. However, when I use this, and try to read the cell following its use, I get an error message (with the "helpful" code 9999). How does one read the results of a previously written formula?

Comment: I've tagged your question as suggested under **Support** on [the Viewpoint toolkit page](https://www.viewpointusa.com/product/ni-labview-toolkits/xlsx-toolkit/), although it appears to be a previously unused tag (shrug). I'm not familiar with the toolkit but are you sure the second VI should be configured for `Int32 Cell Address`, rather than `Formula Cell Address` like the first one?